# why this richedit window doesn't show up when I put the code in class?

Tags: c++, oop, winapi, richedit

It compiles and runs with no error. The only thing is that the window doesn't show up. The destructor should stay forever until I close the window by mouse ?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <richedit.h>

class richEdit {
  HWND richeditWindow;
  richEdit() {
    HMODULE richedit_library = LoadLibrary("Msftedit.dll");
    if (NULL == richedit_library) abort();

    HINSTANCE hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(0);
    richeditWindow = CreateWindowExW (
      WS_EX_TOPMOST,
      MSFTEDIT_CLASS,
      L"window text",
      WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | ES_MULTILINE | WS_VISIBLE,
      0, 0, 500, 500,
      NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL
    );
  }
  ~richEdit() {
    MSG msg;
    while( GetMessageW( &msg, richeditWindow, 0, 0 ) ) {
      TranslateMessage( &msg );
      DispatchMessageW( &msg );
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  richEdit re();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
richEdit re();
```

Is not a *default-constructed* object of type `richEdit`. Is a declaration of a function named `re` that takes no arguments and returns a `richEdit`.

You want this instead:

```
richEdit re;
```

...or in *C++11*:

```
richEdit re{};
```

Note that a blocking *destructor* is something that will certainly give you headaches in the future.